# Store multiple data in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, functional-programming, parameter-passing

I am trying to figure out a way on how to store data in some kind of list or array in javascript. I have three variables called id, left and top. All are in the function

id: index of an element that is passed to the function as parameter.
left: calculated within the function
top: calculated within the function

What I am looking for is each time I call the function with different id, the function should be able to calculate and store left and top and in some way store id,left and top so that I can access them in another function call.

Or can I use objects to use the values?

function:

```
function getCoordinates(id) {
    scroll_value_Y = document.getElementById("svg_editor").scrollTop;
    scroll_value_X = document.getElementById("svg_editor").scrollLeft;
    offset_x = 298;
    offset_y = 102;
    var p = $('#' + id);
    var offset = p.offset();
    var left = Math.round(offset.left - offset_x + scroll_value_X);
    var top = offset.top - offset_y + scroll_value_Y;
    //something to store
}
```

use in another function call :

```
drawAggregate(getCoordinates(a1).left, getCoordinates(a1).top, getCoordinates(a2).left, getCoordinates(a2).top);
```

Or something like that. How can I implement this?

Comment: Yes, use an array. `var a = []` and `a.push({top: top, left: left})` (treating the index as the id).

Comment: You can return a json object with these 3 attributes. Your json will look like `{id: <your id>, left: <left position>, top: <top position>}`

Comment: are you talking about memoization (like coordinate for each id is compute once only)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, just return an `Object`.

```
function getCoordinates(id) {
    scroll_value_Y = document.getElementById("svg_editor").scrollTop;
    scroll_value_X = document.getElementById("svg_editor").scrollLeft;
    offset_x = 298;
    offset_y = 102;
    var p = $('#' + id);
    var offset = p.offset();
    var left = Math.round(offset.left - offset_x + scroll_value_X);
    var top = offset.top - offset_y + scroll_value_Y;

    // Here we create and return an object with two keys: left and top
    return {
      top: top,
      left: left
    }
}
```

And, in order to avoid computing the values twice, you could store the values in other objects `a1Coords` and `a2Coords`:

```
var a1Coords = getCoordinates(a1);
var a2Coords = getCoordinates(a2);

drawAggregate(a1Coords.left, a1Coords.top, a2Coords.left, a2Coords.top);
```

I assume that your coordinates change every time, so you don't actually want to store coordinates inside the `getCoordinates` function but only compute and return them.

Answer (score 1):

Shure you can use objects.

You can just pass object into function, like this:

```
(function(){

    function incId(data){
    var id = data.id;
    data.id = id++;
    }

    function checkId(data){
    console.log(data.id);
    }

   var data = {id:0};
   incId(data);
   checkId(data);
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return an object:

```
function getCoordinates(id)
{
    var scroll_value_Y = document.getElementById("svg_editor").scrollTop;
    var scroll_value_X = document.getElementById("svg_editor").scrollLeft;

    var offset_x = 298;
    var offset_y = 102;

    var p = $('#' + id);
    var offset = p.offset();

    return {
        left: Math.round(offset.left - offset_x + scroll_value_X),
        top : offset.top - offset_y + scroll_value_Y
    };
}

var coords1 = getCoordinates(a1);
var coords2 = getCoordinates(a2);

drawAggregate(coords1.left, coords1.top, coords2.left, coords2.top);
```